# How to do a foreach insert query for a field?

Tags: php, validation, foreach, csv

I have a field where i know for sure the entries would be something like Edward, John, Jacob in a input field.

Now, i am trying to insert a new row for each of the people.  I am doing this:

```
$person = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['person']);

foreach($person_array as $value) 
{ 
$insert = "INSERT INTO people (Person)
VALUES ('".$value."')";

$query = mysql_query($insert) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error()); 

}
```

Using the above query i am unable to insert into the table.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: $person is a string, not an array. What are you foreaching over? Nix the foreach and just stick $person into the query.

Comment: foreach is meant to loop through array elements. You're expecting the return value of mysql_real_escape_string() to be an array. The function itself clearly says that it escapes a string.

Comment: 1 use $_POST instead of $POST. $POST is nothing in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $_POST['person'] is indeed a value as such : "John, Edward, Jacob" then it's just a string; you'll need to convert it into an array with explode. Also, it should be $_POST not $POST.

```
$person = explode(',', $_POST['person']);
```

Then you can run your foreach function.

Comment: Hey i tried this but when i do a var_dump it only shows me the first person now all the other people...

Comment: @ariel Can you post your `<input>`s on your question so we can see your HTML?

Comment: @mbj it worked i double checked my tables.  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you got what you needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs should look like: `<input type="text" name="person[]">`

Assuming that is the case, you are running `mysql_real_escape_string` on an array.

Try this:

```
$person = $POST['person'];
foreach($person as $value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO people (Person) VALUES ('$value')";
    $query = mysql_query($insert) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [DampeS8N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509610/dampes8n) commented, `mysql_real_escape_string` returns a string. You can't apply it to an `Array`.

Also, [anuragbh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543331/anuragbh) found a typo on your code, it's `$_POST` instead of `$POST`.

Lastly, try escaping the special chars inside your loop.

```
foreach($_POST['person'] as $value)
{
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    //your query here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you get? Is its primary key auto-incremented?

Also:

```
$person = mysql_real_escape_string($POST['person']);
```

Should be:

```
$person = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['person']);
```